# Why don't all metrics have trivial determinant?

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, determinant

What is wrong with this argument?

Let $V$ be a vector space and $g$ an inner product. There exists an orthonormal basis for $V$. That is, in this basis $(g_{ij})=I$. But then given any other basis, the new matrix representation of $g$ is congruent to $I$. Hence the determinant of $g$ in any basis is always 1.

On a manifold you have a metric on the tangent space at each point. But we can always find an orthornomal basis for that tangent space and so $\det g_p=1$. But then this means $\text{vol}_M= \sqrt{\det g}dx^1\wedge\dots\wedge dx^n=dx^1\wedge\dots\wedge dx^n$.

Comment: Why is $(g_{ij})=I$? Suppose $V=\mathbb R^2$ and $g(x,y)=x^T\pmatrix{1\\ &2}y$, what orthonormal basis would make the matrix of $g$ equal to $I$?

Comment: Just finding an ON basis for the tangent space at a single point, or even a moving ON frame, is not the same thing as finding a *coordinate system* such that the expression for $g_{ij}$ (with respect to the induced basis $(\partial/\partial x^i)$) becomes $I$ at *every* point (this is not possible in general).

Comment: @user1551: Any ON basis with respect to *that* inner product, of course! (Not with respect to the standard inner product on $\mathbb{R}^2$, but that's not what this question is about.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When changing the basis with respect to which a bilinear form is represented, we have$$A'=P^tAP,$$where $A$ and $A'$ are the representing matrices and $P$ is the transition matrix. When one of the matrices represents $g$ with respect to an orthonormal basis, we have$$A'=P^tIP,$$ and thus$$\det A'=\det P^t\cdot\det P=(\det P)^2.$$The last sentence in the question, regarding volume forms, indeed holds.

Comment: +1. Perhaps the OP forgot that $P$ and $P^t$ (_not_ $P^{-1}$) are used to obtain $A'$.

Comment: Exactly what happened!